# fail accessing constructor public CameraPreview(Context fragment, Camera camera, PreviewCallback previewCb, AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb) in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I tried to call a constructor in the fragment class. However it shows an error.

This is the constructor code:

```
public CameraPreview(Context fragment, Camera camera,
                     PreviewCallback previewCb,
                     AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb) {
    super(fragment);
    mCamera = camera;
    previewCallback = previewCb;
    autoFocusCallback = autoFocusCb;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);

    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
```

Then I try to access is within another fragment class:

`mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
   FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
   preview.addView(mPreview);`

I noticed the problem was "this". How I should solve it? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this call is in fragment, then it should be:

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
```

`this.getActivity()` will get you your Context, `Fragment` does not extend Context class, so this is actually wrong naming : `Context fragment`.

Comment: I try that, however if I use this.getActivity(), eclipse will prompt me that the line of codes before it are unreachable.
I know Fragment does not extend Context, it is just a variable name though, just to make the problem clear :p

Comment: If Eclipse gives you error that some code is unreachable, then it means that you code will always call return; before some code will get executed. Example: `void fun() { return; int n=0; }`, code: 'int n=0;' is unreachable.

Comment: Wow, yeah you're right. I have "return" code before it. Problem solved. Thank a lot. cheers.